# Express not sending object from Service to API controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

Trying to understand user authentication in order to integrate into my web app. I've been following http://www.sitepoint.com/user-authentication-mean-stack/ as a guide.

I'm a novice when it comes to webdev, so I'm having trouble searching the right thing to fix my problem. The issue is when I try to register a new user my object isn't getting received in my api controller.

**register.controller.js**

```
(function () {
  angular
  .module('misplaced')
  .controller('registerCtrl', registerCtrl);

  registerCtrl.$inject = ['$location', 'authentication'];
  function registerCtrl($location, authentication) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.onSubmit = function () {
    authentication
      .register(vm.credentials)
      .error(function(err){
        alert(err);
      })
      .then(function(){
        $location.path('profile');
      });
  };
```

**authentication.service.js**

```
(function () {
 angular
 .module('misplaced')
 .service('authentication', authentication);

 authentication.$inject = ['$http', '$window'];
 function authentication ($http, $window) {
   register = function(user) {
   return $http.post('/api/register', user).success(function(data){
     saveToken(data.token);
   });
 };
```

**authentication.js**

```
module.exports.register = function(req, res) {

  var user = new User();
  user.name = req.body.name;
  user.email = req.body.email;
  user.setPassword(req.body.password);

  user.save(function(err) {
    var token;
    token = user.generateJwt();
    res.status(200);
    res.json({
      "token" : token
    });
  });
};
```

Through some console.log I've tracked that the object gets created fine from the register.controller and gets passed to authentication.service fine, but when I try to console.log the object in authentication.js file it's empty. Can someone help explain to me what might be happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you see in the console if you log `data` in the success handler in your `authentication.service.js`?

Comment: Ah ok, I just re-read your question, so I guess if you attempt to console.log the `req.body` in your server side controller, that comes back as null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like an Express configuration issue, you may not be using the `bodyParser` module in Express.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

This will allow your middleware to access the request body properties in `req.body`